# How to prevent MP4 files from downloading on Linux & Firefox with JWPlayer

Tags: linux, firefox, jwplayer

I have JWPlayer running on my system, with no issues -except one. For some reason, on Firefox on a Linux CentOS machine, JWPlayer will not automatically play the MP4 video. I will give the user an option to "Open with" (Media Player/Default) or "Save File".

How do I prevent users from being able to download the MP4 file? My JWPlayer setup is set up for streaming & HTML5 fallback, as shown below. These are served from Amazon CloudFront.

```
jwplayer('container').setup({
    playlist: [{
        ga: { },
       title: '$title',
       image: 'XXX.png',
       sources: [{ 
            file: '$cf_stream_uri$stream_url'
        },{
            file: '$down_url'
        }]
    }],
    height: 600,
    primary: 'html5',
    width: 800
});";
```

Like I said, this works for every other browser/device (including iOS) without problem.

[Firefox JWPlayer popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfyrG.jpg)

Thank you!

Comment: a few suggestions - try making `primary: 'flash'`, put your `ga` tag outside of the `playlist` braces.

very odd that it would default to downloading. i will have to try it on linux to duplicate the behavior.